# Getting date from table and finding its difference from current date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get date from a table and find its difference in years.I have tried the following query which is actually not correct.I dont know how to get date from a table and use it directly in DATEDIFF function.Can anyone help me out?

```
  SELECT empname,DATEDIFF(year,dob,GETDATE()) as year,DATEDIFF(month,dob,GETDATE()) as month from Employee1;
```

I am trying it in SQL server.
If i give dates like `"29-08-2014"` and `"29-04-2015"`.It should give me:
year : 0 month : 8

Comment: Change `dateofbirth`to `dob` in the datediff function (you can't use an alias on the same level in the query as it was defined). Beware that this simple calculation will return incorrect difference for some dates.

Comment: Beware, DATEDIFF of YEAR between 31st December 2014 and 1st January 2015 is 1. This is not wrong, it's the way DATEDIFF is documented to work.

Comment: Thanks guys.This query worked for me                                       SELECT empname,DATEDIFF(year,dob,GETDATE()) as year,DATEDIFF(month,dob,GETDATE())%12 as month from Employee1;

Answer (score 0):

You can read this oracle document, [DATEDIFF](http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/column_conversion_functions011.htm)